# exc_bad_access code=1 address=0*0 when using UIActivityviewController in iphone

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, uiactivityviewcontroller

Here is my code where I use to share an image vaia facebook:

```
NSArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archive];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = 
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:array 
                                      applicationActivities:nil]; 
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, 
                                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                     UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                     UIActivityTypeMail,
                                     UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this is working fine in simulator, but when I am testing it on real ipad 3, it force closes saying the error

```
exc_bad_access code=1 address=0*0
```

in this line

```
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, 
                                         UIActivityTypePrint,
                                         UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                         UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                         UIActivityTypeMail,
                                         UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                         UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
```

can any one find me out what I have missed here?

edited part:

I have checked everything and `array` is not nil. if I comment out the line `activityVc.exclude....`

then it force closes and says

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller
```

Comment: Check if `array` is nil

Comment: It the array is nil then how it is working on simulator with the perfect image?

Comment: If your `array` is not nil, check the `UIActivity` objects in the array and make sure they're constructed properly. Maybe something in that data is not correct.

Comment: @Reyjohn It is quite possible that `array` or `archive` could be `nil` on a real device on not on the simulator. Did you actually check?

Comment: Ok I am checking, but the error is showing in the line where I am excluding the other sharing apps and keeping just the facebook. So is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your iPad's os?,

it must have **ios 6** or above version for `UIActivityViewController`
[image]

you can check version using

```
   NSString *reqSysVer = @"6.0";
   NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
      {

       //use UIActivityViewController here
      }
```